# Make a Role that always is authorized even when not listed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, roleprovider

In MVC3 is there a way to make a role (*SuperAdmin*) that is **ALWAYS** authorized even if not explicitly listed in the Roles list?

For example with this markup...

`[Authorize(Roles="Accounting")]`

Even though I'm not in the *Accounting* role, as a *SuperAdmin* is there a way to be Authorized for this Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your customized `AuthorizeAttribute` where in the `AuthorizeCore` method you can implement the extra logic.

A simple example without proper error handling:

```
public class AuthorizeSuperAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) 
     {    
         IPrincipal user = httpContext.User; 
         if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated && user.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                return true;

         return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);    
     }
}
```

Then you can use it normally on your actions:

```
[AuthorizeSuperAdmin(Roles="Accounting")]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
}
```

Comment: @Jared Eric's answer is much more flexible and generic my solution is little bit oversimplified, but it also works :)

Comment: I like how this is laid out.  If anything I'd probably shorten the `[AthorizeSuperAdmin()]` to something like `[Auth()]`, but that's a small change.  So for example if I wanted the Attribute to be `[Auth()]` would I lay out the class like `public class AuthAttribute...`  Also the file that you place this in...  Is there a required place for it or just wherever I feel it fits best in the project (Infrastructure folder).  Lastly would something like Fluent Security for MVC make this any better/easier? http://www.fluentsecurity.net/

Comment: His may be more flexible, but if I'm reading it correctly you would actually have to do markup on any Controller that you don't want to require a login for...correct?  The login enabled sections of the site are so few and far between that I'd prefer to markup when I need it then to have to mark it up when I don't.

Comment: @Jared you can name your Attribute as you like. e.g: `public class AuthAttribute` and use it as `[Auth()]`. In our projects we put these attributes into a `Infrastruture/Filters` folders (the AuthorizeAttribute is basically an autohorization filter). I'm not familiar with Fluent Security MVC so I canno't help you with that.

Comment: @nemesv If I were to use your verion, I'd modify it so there would be a GlobalAuthorize attribute and register it in Global.asax.  Then all controllers would allow whatever is authorized by the GlobalAuthorize.

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend reading [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

First, create your `AnonymousAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, 
                AllowMultiple = false,    
                Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowAnonymousAttribute : Attribute 
{ 
}
```

Second, create your `GlobalAuthorize` attribute:

```
public sealed class GlobalAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool bypassAuthorization = 
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor
                         .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), 
                                    true)
            || filterContext.ActionDescriptor
                            .ControllerDescriptor
                            .IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute),
                                       true)
            || (filterContext.RequestContext
                            .HttpContext
                            .User != null
                && filterContext.RequestContext
                                .HttpContext
                                .User
                                .IsInRole("SuperAdmin"));

        if (!bypassAuthorization)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Third, register GlobalAuthorize in your Global Filters (global.asax):

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
  filters.Add(new GlobalAuthorize());
}
```

Now all controllers require the user to be logged in to access.  Controllers OR controller Methods can be allowed Anonymous access with the AllowAnonymous attribute.  Additionally, all methods are allowed by users in the SuperAdmin role.

Comment: I'll take a look at the article that you linked.  I was also curious if another framework similar to Fluent Security might be better?  http://www.fluentsecurity.net/